# «Дух сообщества» на Мете не переведен

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, дух-сообщества

На Мете профиль пользователя Community/Дух сообщества не переведен:

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community

> Community♦ (модератор)
>
> Hi, I'm not really a person.
>   ...