# Слетел перевод профиля Духа

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, профиль-участника, дух-сообщества

Насколько я помню, в [профиле Духа сообщества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/%D0%94%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0) описание было русифицировано, теперь же оно на английском:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Еще бы и ссылку из профиля надо на русскоязычную версию переназначить в конечном итоге.

Старые дефекты:

- [«Дух сообщества» на Мете не переведен](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1128/176217)
- [Обновить ссылки в профиле Духа сообщества](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1127/176217)

Любопытно, что если смотреть профиль через приложение iOS, то он русифицирован, и даже ссылка ведёт на [мета вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392/176217):

> [image: ios]

Похоже на то, что строки раньше были вне Transifex и редактировались модераторами, и приложение продолжает использовать старый механизм. В то время как сайт перешёл на Transifex.

Comment: Да вроде давно уже.

Comment: @Suvitruf дубль есть?

Comment: Я не постил, думал, что это нормально )=

Comment: @Suvitruf можно на аву Вовку из Тредесятого царства брать :)

Comment: А полследнее посещение тольео мне кажется странным?

Comment: @Qwertiy а ноль просмотров профиля?

Comment: @alexolut это заговор! Администрация скрывает правду!

Comment: @alexolut `if(userId == -1) { if(ios) print(hardcoded_string); else print(trans_string); }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавил переводы в Transifex. Каждая строка переведена отдельно, поэтому тут приведу общий скриншот:

> [image: скрин из Transifex]

Должно появиться на сайте после обновления БД и пересборки движка.

Comment: А юморить можно? Я б вместо "фоновый процесс" написал "ниндзя" )

Comment: Опечатка. "Раз в ча`с`".

Comment: @Suvitruf в "чаТ" тоже хорошо :) Ща поправлю. Там был раньше демон, кстати.

Comment: @alexolut кажется, вот старое описание: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6001/181472

Comment: @NickVolynkin КМ сказал, что попадание строк в транзифекс вообще было багом. Сейчас вернулся прежний вариант редактирования профиля. Не знаю, доступно всем ромбами или только сотрудникам.

Comment: @alexolut о, действительно, вернулось описание. Редактировать его могу.